# Extra in EXPLAIN printing - 'Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables'

Tags: mysql, explain

I have a simple table called 'million_words'. It has one row with two columns -> id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY & word VARCHAR(50 NOT NULL.

I run this query -: `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM million_words WHERE word = '-anon'`

The `Extra` column then prints : `'Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables`, even though the row is clearly present in the table.

Whats wronf

Answer (score 15):

**From MySQL documentation**:

"*Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables*":
MySQL has read all const (and system) tables and notice that the WHERE clause is always false. Refer [**`this`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html)

---

The table has at most one matching row, which is read at the start of the query. **Because there is only one row, values from the column in this row can be regarded as constants by the rest of the optimizer**. const tables are very fast because they are read only once.

const is used when you compare all parts of a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE index` to constant values. Refer [**`this`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html#jointype_const)